# How to hide the header on an Xsl Fo, page overflow

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a header, a body, and a footer set up for an Xsl Fo page sequence. There are certain items displayed on this page in blocks with a `keep-together.within-page` value of `1`. This works really well for the most part, but I've noticed that when stuff that will span an entire page or more absolutely has to break it will end up on a new page and then get cut (which is fine) but then the header gets drawn in the middle of this making everything look a little gross/confusing (not fine) as whatever remains is drawn onto the next page.

So I'm wondering, is there some way to suppress the header on content overflow into the next page?

Or is there some way with alternative page sequences or something to achieve what I want?

Sorry for the vagueness here, and a lack of a current working representation of what's going on. I am very new to Xsl Fo, and most of our working code is under an abstracted framework, but if I knew of the correct directives or if this was possible I'm sure I could implement them into the framework and get things working.

Edit: I have attached a picture to hopefully clarify what is going on
[image: When a block overflows from one page to the next, the header still shows up.]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: @TonyGraham Done! Please let me know if there is anything else you may need.

Comment: From that screenshot: it's worth checking if you can modify the table layout to create more room for the column that fills up first. If your second column is 30 cm high but the third column only contains "performed by" and "date/time", you could make the second column wider, the third column narrower and place the "date/time" field below "performed by" instead of next to it. It's worth some effort to avoid "my cell is longer than the page".

Answer (score 0):

You could put the content that you want to hide in an `fo:marker` and use `fo:retrieve-marker` in the `fo:static-content` that flows into the 'region-before' region.

The trick is to put a copy of the 'real' `fo:marker` before each of the blocks with the `keep-together` and also put an empty `fo:marker` with the same `marker-class-name` as the first thing inside the block.  (I don't know what your XSL-FO markup is like, but you may need to put an `fo:wrapper` around each block as a place to put the 'real' marker.)

If `retrieve-position` is `first-including-carryover` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#retrieve-position), then you should get an empty `fo:marker` for blocks that broke across the page boundary and get the 'real' `fo:marker` on other pages.

Comment: Does this work for something like a headers that's defined for my entire page-sequence, or does this mean I'm breaking my header out into it's own thing and I'm telling FOP/Xsl Fo to insert my header at the nearest place it fit?